# Angular - Select dropdown list is blank

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, angular-ngselect

In my Angular-12, I have this JSON response from the API endpoint:

```
{
  "message": "vehicle Model Detail.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "vehiclemakes": [{
        "name": "Freightliner",
        "id": 15
      },
      {
        "name": "Honda",
        "id": 13
      },
      {
        "name": "Renault",
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "Suzuki",
        "id": 16
      },
      {
        "name": "Toyota",
        "id": 4,
      },
      {
        "name": "Volkswagen",
        "id": 6
      },
      {
        "name": "Volvo",
        "id": 5
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Service:

```js
public getParameters(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.api.baseURL + 'parameters', this.httpOptions);
}
```

Component:

```js
vehicles!: any[];

loadAllVehicles() {
  this.vehiclemodelService.getParameters().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.vehicles = data.results.vehicles;
    },
    error => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
    }
  );
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loadAllVehicles();
}
```

I am to load this in a dropdown select list:

HTML:

```
<ng-select [items]="vehicles"
   [selectOnTab]="true"
   [searchable]="true"
   bindValue="name"
   bindLabel="make_id"
   placeholder="Select Vehicle Make"
   [multiple]="false"
   [clearable]="true"
   required
   formControlName="make_id">
</ng-select>
```

When I loaded the form and click on the select dropdown list, it appears that data is there but it displays nothing.

How do I get this sorted out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues

1. As @Nenad mentioned, `results.vehicles` is not valid in your JSON. You have to use `results.vehiclemakes`.
2. **`make_id` is not valid** in the object of `vehiclemakes`. Meanwhile, `bindLabel` property is used to display the label, while `bindValue` is used for value. With existing code, the **generated options will display *id as label* with the *name as value***.

```
<ng-select bindValue="name"
     bindLabel="make_id">
</ng-select>
```

---

### Solution

1. Assign `vehicles` with `data.results.vehiclemakes`.
2. Set `bindLabel` with `name` and `bindValue` with `id`.

> .component.ts

```js
loadAllVehicles() {
  this.vehiclemodelService.getParameters().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.vehicles = data.results.vehiclemakes;
    },
    error => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
    }
  );
}
```

> .component.html

```
<ng-select [items]="vehicles"
     [selectOnTab]="true"
     [searchable]="true"
     bindValue="id"
     bindLabel="name"
     placeholder="Select Vehicle Make"
     [multiple]="false"
     [clearable]="true"
     required
     formControlName="make_id">
</ng-select>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-952u8c)

Comment: Thanks. Resolved.  Do you have an idea of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68865510/angular-how-to-use-tusharghoshbd-ngx-datatable-for-pined-datatable-with-row-de

Answer (score 3):

Because this.vehicles is filled asyncronously, that's how .subscribe() works. When your ng-select is rendered, this.vehicles does not contains your api response.

A simple way to handle this :

html :

```html
<ng-select [items]="vehicles$ | async"
     [selectOnTab]="true"
     [searchable]="true"
     bindValue="name"
     bindLabel="make_id"
     placeholder="Select Vehicle Make"
     [multiple]="false"
     [clearable]="true"
     required
     formControlName="make_id">
</ng-select>
```

ts :

```js
vehicles$!: Observable<any[]>;

loadAllVehicles() {
  this.vehicles$ = this.vehiclemodelService.getParameters().pipe(
    map(data => data.results.vehicles)
    catchError(() => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
      return of(null);
   }),
  );
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loadAllVehicles();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In you sample data, the property is called `results.vehiclemakes`, and when you are assigning value to `this.vehicles` , you used `results.vehicles`. So, just change that to:

```js
this.vehicles = data.results.vehiclemakes;
```